# Symbian S60 3rd ed. FP2 SDK registration

Tags: sdk, emulation, symbian, nokia, license-key

Using Nokia SDK emulator requires registration (at least for *Symbian S60 3rd ed. FP2, S^3*). Despite SDK is free, it asks for "username/serial" number or suggests to "*load registration information from the file*" after trial period. Since Nokia site shutdown it appears that new SDK users can't register it and use the emulator in development. Also one can't use serial from other machine.

Is there a way to set emulator up and running? (May be getting serial in alternative way.)

P.S. You can download Symbian SDK [here](http://n8delight.blogspot.com/2014/05/for-developers-re-up-of-symbian.html).

Comment: Same problem. They effectively killed this system. I can't even fix bugs in my older apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now we can reset the 14 day trial using simple bat file. You can run it without Admin rights. It works on both x64 and x86 Windows machines. It requires "wmic", "regini" and "reg" to work.

Tested for S60v3, S60v3FP1, S60v3FP2, S60v5 and S^3 SDKs, with Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 (and XP too as commented). It won't work in Windows 11, because Microsoft removed "wmic" tool in Windows 11.

```
@echo off
REM this for loop gets User Security ID and assign it to userSID variable
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set userSID=%%a
      goto :end
   )   
)
:end

REM this echo used to create temporary text file for REGINI to edit permissions
echo \Registry\user\%userSID%\Software\Nokia\Product Registration [1 5 7 17]>temporary.txt
REGINI temporary.txt
del temporary.txt

REM this reg command deletes registry folder to reset SDK trial 
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nokia\Product Registration" /f
echo All registration info deleted already.
echo Your S60 Emulator have 14 days trial again.
pause
```

Comment: Works on Windows XP SP3 x86

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass this by unzipping the installer exe file with 7-zip. It will contain other exe files, unzip those as well, keep doing this until you extracted everything. At the end, you end up with a directory structure like this:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\Nokia_3510_SDK\install\InstallerData\Installer\$VOB_3510I_CA_SDK$\InstallerProjects\Imports
```

With the SDK I used, this folder contained one final JAR file which you can also unzip, and this contained the phone emulator as exe file.